# How to include external libraries placed outside the webroot in a custom module?

Tags: 8, javascript

I'd like to use an external library in my custom module. So, I added it as a dependency in the *composer.json* of my custom module.

Since the *drupal/recommended-project* template places the *vendor/* directory outside the *webroot*, we can't access it directly from the *.libraries.yml* file like this:

```
chosen:
  js:
    /vendor/harvesthq/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js: {}
```

According to [this Jaypan's post](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-01-23/add-vendor-library-via-librariesyml#comment-12791719), the solution for this issue is to use the [Vendor Stream Wrapper module](https://www.drupal.org/project/vendor_stream_wrapper).
So, I added this module as a dependency, both in *.info.yml* and *composer.json* files of my module, following the example in the Jaypan's post.
Then I updated my *.libraries.yml* file:

```
chosen:
  js:
    vendor://harvesthq/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js: {}
```

However, the Chosen library is still not loaded (I mention that I cleared the Drupal cache) from what I see in my browser:

```
TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function
```

Here is the dependencies declaration in the *composer.json* of my module:

```
"require": {
  "harvesthq/chosen": "^1.8",
  "drupal/vendor_stream_wrapper": "^1.3"
}
```

The dependency declaration in my *.info.yml file*:

```
dependencies:
  - vendor_stream_wrapper:vendor_stream_wrapper
```

The `hook_form_alter()` method in my *.module* file:

```php
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
  if ($form_object instanceof EntityFormInterface) {
    $entity = $form_object->getEntity();
    if (in_array($entity->getEntityTypeId(), ['node', 'user'])) {
      $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/chosen';
    }
  }
}
```

I mention that PHP goes well through the line `$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/chosen';`.

Comment: Is the file showing up in the HTML source?

Comment: _I added this module as a dependency, both in .info.yml and composer.json files of my module_ Did you make sure to download and install it?

Comment: No, _chosen.jquery.min.js_ is not showing up in the source. I just have my custom JS file that is loaded from the _js/_ directory of my module.

Comment: I did a `ls vendor/harvesthq/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js` in CLI that confirms the file is present.

Comment: _Where_ is this library being depended on? Is it being attached in a preprocess function? libraries.yml defines the library files, but does not automatically inject them to pages.

Comment: I edited my question to add the `hook_form_alter()` method.

Comment: Have you cleared the registry after adding the libraries file?

Comment: Use a Composer installer extender and have theme libs installed in a dedicated directory inside the webroot. Typically that's web/libraries/ or web/themes/custom/mytheme/libs.

Comment: You can find instructions for the installers extender method here: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/chosen/blob/8.x-2.x/README.txt if you decide to go down that route

Comment: Do you use Wikimedia's Composer merge plugin to have your custom module's composer.json picked up? If not, and because it's a custom module, require Chosen and the vendor stream wrapper in your project's composer.json, not in your custom module.

Comment: @Jaypan, if you mean to rebuild the registry, it seems only Drush 8 with D7 allow it.

Comment: @Clive, in fact my question is related to a [contributed module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_chosen_select), so I was looking for a way that doesn't require the user to do any extra work to install the module. That's why I wanted to use Vendor Stream Wrapper as a dependency of my module.

Comment: @leymannx, My _chosen.jquery.min.js_ is well installed in _vendor/_ by Composer. Do you know a Composer installer extender that doesn't require any extra work from the user?

Comment: BTW, the Wikimedia's Composer merge plugin seems to be deprecated, according to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2912387).

Comment: No, you need to clear the registry (aka cache) at Admin -> Configuration -> Development -> Performance. Or you need to run `drush cr`.

Comment: All right, thank you @Jaypan, yes I did (I mentioned it in my question but may be it was not clear between the Drupal cache and the browser cache, sorry... I edited it to make it clear).

Comment: The code you've shown should be working. It looks fine. I'm suspecting it's something else in your system that will require some deeper debugging. I'm using the module exactly as you've described, and it works fine.

Comment: I remember the 7.x version of the Semantic UI API module providing a Drush command to download and unzip its library. You could have the same in a form submit handler the users have to trigger via a button click. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/semantic_ui_api/-/blob/7.x-1.x/drush/semantic_ui_api.drush.inc (Disclaimer: please check on shell_exec and security considerations yourself).

Comment: I've just updated Vendor Stream Wrapper, applying some submitted patches. See if the newest version works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan. Same issue with version 1.5. Just in case, the code is available [here](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/domain_chosen_select/-/tree/8.x-1.x).

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I use the module both in my own projects, as well as some contributed projects, and it works fine. Can you try your module on a clean Drupal installation? I'm thinking you have something in your system that's disrupting this, as your code looks fine.

Comment: You're right @Jaypan, it works on a clean Drupal installation. Good catch! I should have tested that... Thank you very much.